# Cloudflare or Incapsula CDN without changing DNS

Tags: dns, cdn, cloudflare, incapsula

I'm looking for a low cost/free CDN that can serve my static files. (I will serve dynamic files from my own server)

From the plans it seems like free plan includes CDN:
https://www.cloudflare.com/plans
http://www.incapsula.com/pricing-and-plans/compare-all-plans/?src=176
But after registartion Cloudflare wanted me to change my DNS records to their DNS servers.

Is it not possible to serve some files from their server without changing DNS records ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it not possible to serve some files from their server without changing DNS records ?

Correction: see comment above from [xxdesmus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282088/xxdesmus)

<s>Not from CloudFlare, atleast not unless you want to serve the files from another domain.</s> CloudFlare is a lot more than a simple CDN to serve static files, for example it's going to try and block malicious attacks to your site as well, and to do this it needs to be set as your authorative name server.

From a CDN point of view, the advantage for you with CloudFlare is that the caching is automatic (unless you overide this with custom page rules), so it's easy to set up.

If this isn't a good fit for what you want to do, there are plenty of other options where you can specify on a file by file basis which assets are to be served from a CDN. For most sites I manage, even using a paid service like [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) costs hardly anything.

Answer (score 21):

@David above isn't correct when he says "Not from CloudFlare". That isn't the case.

CloudFlare offers a [CNAME pointing option](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/zone-setups/partial-setup) whereby you can keep using your own DNS, and then pointing CNAME records through CloudFlare (not A records, but CNAME records).  So you can use a CNAME setup like this without changing your DNS, and yet still route content through our service. Just to note, this CNAME setup option is available at the business level and above.

Disclaimer: I work for CloudFlare.

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing out about CNAME pointing, I hadn't come across this before ;)

Comment: business level and above ...keep scrolling down

Answer (score 6):

I work for Incapsula. You can on-board our services via CName changes only.

The on-boading is fairly simply and should only take 2-3 minutes. For step-by-step you can watch this Youtube video, by one of our clients: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJAszU9_guA

Answer (score 4):

We should probably have linked to the directions for [CNAME setup](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/zone-setups/partial-setup) (I also work for CloudFlare). The process is manual at this point, which means a customer would have to contact us to work on the request.